# Unable to delete Active Directory user

Tags: active-directory

I have one particular AD user, nothing really special about them that I'm aware of, that I'm unable to delete.  The error is the "You do not have sufficient privileges to delete..." with the CN data which oddly has something about iPad App and ExchangeActiveSyncDevices in it and then "...or this object is protected from accidental deletion."

The accidental deletion protection option is off.  I can't delete it from an account escalated to administrator nor from a full administrator login.  This is not the only person with an iPad that has synced to our Exchange server.  Is that a real clue or is it a misleading error?  What else could be blocking deletion?

Comment: Can you view the object security privileges on that account?

Comment: @Davidw Yes, and "Administrators" has "Full control"

Comment: Have you tried using an elevated Powershell prompt?

Comment: If a user account has child objects, and the AD administrative account does not have the required permission on the child objects, that should be corrected. It's not unusual for AD administrative accounts to not have full permission to Exchange objects.

Comment: OK, I can't remove that account from the Exchange admin center either.  INSUFF_ACCESS_RIGHTS.  I've never run into this before and it's definitely not my first time removing an Exchange user!  :-)  I'll investigate the child objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it finally!  Had to go into ADSI Edit, find the user, go to the Exchange folder under her CN there.  Open that up and take ownership (it was assigned to some random string instead of a real user).  Once doing that I was able to give myself full security control on those objects that no one had control over before (including SELF).  Finally once THAT was complete I could delete her account the normal way.

Comment: Excellent news!

Answer (score 3):

In AD Users and Computers, in the View menu, select the `Users, Contacts, Groups and Computers as Containers` option.

Find your user object there, and you'll probably see some sub-objects beneath the user object, such as certificates or similar things. To delete the user, right-click on the "folder" for the user object, and select **Delete**.

You will then probably get a prompt titled **Confirm Subtree Deletion** that explains the user object contains other objects (i.e. the certs or whatever). Just click OK to confirm deletion.

In Powershell, it's:

```
Remove-ADUser MyUser -recursive -Confirm:$false
```

Comment: Helpful, I can see there are a number of Exchange objects.  Unfortunately I cannot delete them even with escalated powershell.  :-/

Comment: Have you tried deleting the account object (not the sub-objects) from the GUI? It should give you an error message if it can't.

Comment: Indeed, I get a nice permission denied error.  Even with the domain administrator account.  Curious.  Is there extra Exchange permissions that need to be added?

Comment: Sorry not to get back to this earlier. I'd be surprised if that was a problem. Maybe try granting Enterprise Admin to your account if you don't have it? Or yes, try adding yourself to Organization Management for Exchange.

Comment: Already had Enterprise Admin.  Added myself to Exchange Organization Management, still can't delete that user account.  This is so strange.  This is just a very simple user account, nothing at all special about that user!  They didn't have special permissions or anything out of the ordinary at all.  They weren't even here that long so didn't have access to many systems!

Comment: I came across an issue yesterday where I couldn't delete an obsolete Public Folder object. It wasn't an "access denied" error, it said "administrative limit reached". This turns out to be an issue if a multivalued attribute has exceeded the RangeUpper value for the property. In this case, the `proxyAddresses` attribute had > 1240 values, when the limit is 1123. Maybe check multivalued attribs on that account to see if any seem excessive? Might be interesting to try clearing all values from every non-mandatory attribute on the account, one by one (might narrow down any perm issue too).

Comment: Well, it looks like this user, when viewed in ADSI Edit has a whole pile of CN=iPad and CN=iPhone entries under the CN=ExchangeActiveSyncDevices.  Nobody has permissions on them.  Not administrator, not even the user herself!  So, I can't delete them from anywhere, nor give anyone permissions to them...  Seems like a pretty ugly situation, wonder how this even happened?